# WPF: Globaly defined ValueConverter

Tags: .net, wpf

Is there a possibility to declare a `IValueConverter` for an application global, so that if a conversion in a Binding is needed, automatically the appropriate converter is used.

**E.g.**

I have written a `IValueConverter` that converts between `int` and `MySpecialClass`.
I have a `Binding` that has a source that returns an instance of `MySpecialClass` and a target that is `int`.

With that globaly declared `ValueConverter`, the conversion will automatically be done without the need of a converter-declaration with the `Converter`-keyword in the Binding.

Does such a possibility exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [TypeConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) here.